# MFC Class Wizard: an error has occurred in the script of this page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, hook

Trying to create classes from a file using the MFC Class Wizard it displays an error in line 860 at the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\MFC\Typelib\HTML\1033\default.htm" file.

This is on Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with the [Deviare component](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/).

**Note:** Putting an *alert(oFunc.Name);* displays  "get_InterfaceError"

**Note 2:** There are support tickets for similar issues google query: site:support.microsoft.com "class wizard" but I am looking for an answer that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this problem occuring in VS2008. I had solved it by... googling. You need to relax some restrictions in IE (running scipts). Sorry, this is just what I can recall.

Comment: I saw the VS2008 report and there is a solution related to modifying the scripts. But on VS2010 these instructions are incorporated in the class wizard.